# GPG: Publishing a key via WKD works only on GnuPG with "wks-server" enabled

Tags: gnupg

I wanted to try and publish my public key via WKD. I followed some tutorials and managed quite soon to make work enough for https://metacode.biz/openpgp/web-key-directory to tell me that everything is fine.

Next step: try it out. So I tried it out on my significant others Win10/Thunderbird setup - and it wouldn't discover my new key. Indeed, on her rig I could not even make gpg (in the windows shell) make it work:

```
gpg -v --auto-key-locate=clear,wkd,nodefault --locate-key me@me.me
gpg: using pgp trust model
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=3c)
gpg: read_block: read error: Ungültiges Paket
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg: error retrieving 'me@me.me' via WKD: Ungültiger Schlüsselbund
gpg: error retrieving 'me@me.me' via None: Kein öffentlicher Schlüssel
gpg: key "me@me.me" not found: Kein öffentlicher Schlüssel
```

The same happened on my raspberry.

I fiddled around and learned that it works if gpg is compiled with "wks-server" enabled (which it is not on the raspberry pi but is on my main rig).

How do I change that? Because other keys can be imported both on the win10 and the raspberry pi, just mine is a problem.

So:

1. Either I exported my key in a weird way? I used:

   `gpg --no-armor --export me@me.me > filename`

(This implies that you can do it wrong: https://zerokspot.com/weblog/2019/09/28/validating-wkd-setup/)

I also tried without --no-armor, but that did not change anything.

2. My key is slightly unusual in that it has 3 subkeys for E/S/A only each. The reason is that I have the secret key on a Yubikey.

```
gpg -k 
pub   rsa4096 2020-10-09 [SC] [verfällt: 2021-10-09]  
      ***********KEYID************************  
uid   [ unbekannt ] My Alias <alias@me.me>
uid   [ unbekannt ] My Name <me@me.me>
sub   rsa4096 2020-10-09 [E] [verfällt: 2021-10-09]  
sub   rsa4096 2020-10-09 [S] [verfällt: 2021-10-09]  
sub   rsa4096 2020-10-09 [A] [verfällt: 2021-10-09]
```

So, my key can be discovered via WKD, but only if you run GnuPG compliled with wks-server enabled, but not otherwise. I would like to change that so especially Windows users with no idea what they are doing can get my key very easily. Any help?